# What is the web context of Azure DevOps Server 2019 on premises?

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, azure-devops-server-2019, azure-devops-server

I have to upgrade TFS 2017 on premises to DevOps 2019 on premises. With TFS 2017 I used http://servername/tfs/collectionname. Does DevOps 2019 provide a web context like "tfs"? I guess it could be "devops". By other hand, in the installation wizard of DevOps 2019 seems not be available a default web context like "devops". Maybe DevOps 2019 release doesn't provide a web context? Maybe the web context is directly the collection name? If yes, is it possibile to configure a "devops" web context in order to obtain http://servername/devops/collectionname? (this could be useful for internal use of reverse proxy)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing new here. Azure DevOps Server 2019 uses "tfs" as context.

[image]